# Are telecommunications/telepresence questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, topic-scope

[This question](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/31428/group-conference-call-struggling-with-audio-better-mic-suggestions-multiple-m) is about how best to mic groups of people for conference calls.  While it is, in essence, about how to get sound from a number of people and play it back for another group, I'm not sure that it is really on topic here.

The telecommunications industry is kind of a special beast with it's own unique set of hardware and devices designed for dealing with these kinds of problems without the need for supervision by a sound guy.

As these systems are automated and unrelated to sound design, but rather just automatic, it feels like this is really off topic to me.  Do we want to consider these kinds of questions on topic, or should telecommunications be off-topic unless their is a larger sound design related issue (such as having to hook sound reinforcement in to a remote location?)

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not on topic. The systems do not provide any influence for sound designers or engineers, so it's a turn-key solution. Furthermore, what would the creative use be?

Answer (score 2):

I'm responding as this recently came up through someone contacting us directly.

No, mic selection / arrangement for conference calls and such would not be on topic here. While this does *sort* of fall into the realm of live / field recording, we presume such recordings are actually being done *in the presence of the source* and not from a remote location. This stops becoming a sound design & engineering problem very quickly, and becomes more of an IT thing.

There needs to be *some* kind of artistic endeavor behind most questions here, and this more or less fails that test (though folks *are* sometimes perfectionists about sound quality on calls, it's out of our realm)

Answer (score 1):

No, telecommunications is its own field and it should not be on topic here unless there is some other larger tie back to topics generally related to sound design.

Comment: Actually, that's a good point. The enterprise solution is to buy the extension microphones for the conference phone system:-)